# Memory Leak, angularJS $interval

Tags: javascript, intervals

I got a memory leak when doing a interval. I have tried different approaches to fix this but I can't figure it out what's the problem.

my code:

```
updated--
$scope.autoUpdatePageResult = function(group){
    $scope.isAutoUpdate = !$scope.isAutoUpdate;
    storageService.setLocalItem($scope.user + '-auto-update-results', $scope.isAutoUpdate);
    if($scope.isAutoUpdate){
        $scope.startInterval(group);
    }
    else {
        $scope.stopInterval(group);
    }
};
--updated

$scope.startInterval = function(group){
    $scope.updateInterval = $interval(function() {
        $scope.shouldReloadPage = false;
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.update = true;
        $scope.allSessions = [];
        for (var a in $scope.sessions){
            $scope.allSessions[a] = $scope.sessions[a].started;
        }
        delete $scope.sessions;
        $scope.sessionGroup = group.name;
        $scope.getSessions();
    }, 3*1000);
    // 3 sec
};

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    storageService.setLocalItem($scope.user + '-auto-update-results', false);
});

$scope.stopInterval = function() {
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.shouldReloadPage = true;
    if (angular.isDefined($scope.updateInterval)) {
        $interval.cancel($scope.updateInterval);
        $scope.updateInterval = undefined;
    }
};
```

this is how the graph looks like in when updateInterval is triggered and recorded (30 sec):

[image]

UPDATE (not working):

```
$scope.startInterval = function(group){
    $scope.totalIntervals = [];
    $scope.updateInterval = $interval(function() {
        if($scope.totalIntervals.length > 1){
            $interval.cancel($scope.totalIntervals[1]);
        }
        $scope.shouldReloadPage = false;
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.update = true;
        $scope.allSessions = [];
        for (var a in $scope.sessions){
            $scope.allSessions[a] = $scope.sessions[a].started;
        }
        delete $scope.sessions;
        $scope.sessionGroup = group.name;
        $scope.getSessions();  
        $scope.totalIntervals.push($scope.updateInterval);
    }, 3*1000);
};`
```

Comment: Where `stopInterval` is called? Not seen in your code; maybe add a call on destroy.

Comment: You could make heap snapshots/heap allocations and see what is being allocated more and more.

Comment: `stopInterval` on destroy is not working. I tried heap snapshots and heap allocations but I don't really understand what to do with the data i get.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling

Answer (score 0):

You only keep one reference to your last started interval.

Once you stop the Interval, if more than one interval was started since you last stopped one, then only the last running interval will be cancled - and the other intervals will keep running without you having a reference to them.

If you only need one interval at a time, you could simply check your `$scope.updateInterval` before creating a new `$interval`. If it is defined, you cancle it before creating a new and overwriting the reference to the old one.

If you need more than one interval running at a time, you could either keep an array of `$interval` references, and then go through the whole array stopping them (use push to add an interval to the array, and pop when taking one off, to stop it). - Or you could do a loop through `$interval` as it will iterate over all its interval references, then cancleing each.

Comment: I tested, maybe i did something wrong (check my main post).

But it doesn't work, when `$interval.cancel` runs it stops the whole update process it seems even if I just stop one interval.